# Centering a button

Tags: css, button, responsive, center

I am trying to center the button when the page is 767px wide and smaller but it just doesn`t work. I though I have done it by display: center ruby - but this somehow works only in my browser but not on my phone. I tried a lot of things.. but centering objects is just not my thing :D Thank you for any tips.

```
<div class="write-us">
  <a href="contactus.html">NAPIŠTE NÁM</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.write-us a {
    width: 28%;
}
.write-us {
    margin: auto;
}
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] in the question?  An off-site resource/example is not recommended as the question loses all future value one the issue becomes resolved.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Just give a`margin: auto` to the `@media (max-width: 767px) { .write-us a { width: 28%; margin: auto; } }`

Comment: Manas Khandelwal - Thank you very much, it is strange I thought I tried this many times.. It is always the first thinkg I try.. But it works thank you!! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add in CSS `margin: auto;` to the `.write-us a` at the specific `@media`.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px)
.write-us a {
    width: 28%;
    margin: auto;
}
```